# Draw line from text input in SharpGL

Tags: c#, opengl

I want to draw line in SharpGl but this code does not work !

```
void Line_DDA(OpenGL gl,int X0, int Y0, int Xend, int Yend)
    {

        gl.LineWidth(2.5f);
        gl.Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_LINES);


        int dx = Xend - X0;
        int dy = Yend - Y0;
        int steps, k;
        float Xinc, Yinc;
        float x = X0;
        float y = Y0;

        if (Math.Abs(dx) > Math.Abs(dy))
            steps = Math.Abs(dx);
        else
            steps = Math.Abs(dy);

        float fdx = (float)dx;
        float fdy = (float)dy;
        float fsteps = (float)steps;
        Xinc = fdx / fsteps;
        Yinc = fdy / fsteps;

        gl.Vertex((int)x, (int)y);

        for (k = 0; k < steps; k++)
        {
            x += Xinc;
            y += Yinc;
            gl.Vertex((int)x, (int)y);
        }

        gl.End();

    }
```

and when I use

```
             gl.Vertex(10, 100);
             gl.Vertex(110, 110);
```

It's work!

**EDIT:**

This is call block in my code:

```
private void openGLControl_OpenGLDraw(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //  Get the OpenGL object.
        OpenGL gl = openGLControl.OpenGL;

        //  Clear the color and depth buffer.
        gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //  Load the identity matrix.
        gl.LoadIdentity();

        Line_DDA(gl, int.Parse(txtLineX1.Text), int.Parse(txtLineY1.Text), int.Parse(txtLineX2.Text), int.Parse(txtLineY2.Text));
        //drawLine(gl, 110, 120, 100, 100);
    }
```

Why this happen?

Comment: Have you looked at this in a debugger to see what values you're passing to the code? To see what values the code is passing to OpenGL?

Comment: Could you give us sample values ? Ie, x0, y0, xend, yend AND x and y at each tieration ?

Comment: it draws broken line on my machine. I think you have done in mistake while calling the function and passing the value of x0,y0,xend,yend

Comment: Finally I used OpenTK and it woks ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you draw lines using `GL_LINES`, you need to supply 2 vertices for each line segment. Instead, your code supply a single vertex for each line segment, as if the line should be connected with the previous vertex.

Indeed, the solution would be to set the draw mode to `GL_LINE_STRIP` or to supply two vertices for each line segment.

However, I don't understand why you want to draw a straight line with multiple vertices when when they are needed only two points.